# WPDB Prepared Delete

Tags: wpdb

I am attempting to delete a row from my DB.I am using inputs from the user and I need to be able to sanitize using the prepared statement.

The query itself looks like -

```
DELETE FROM wp_thing_assignment WHERE (account_number,user) values (1, 'DudeDev')
```

I am using the following code -

```
    $success = $this->wpdb->query($this->wpdb->prepare(
        "DELETE FROM $this->table_name WHERE
            (account_number,user)
            values (%d, %s)",
            array ( $this->company[$i], $this->employee)
    ));
```

I get this error -

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'values (1, 'USER')' at line 1

Is there any way to salvage this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have just confused syntax with INSERT :) According to manual the [DELETE syntax is](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html):

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name,...)]
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

No `VALUES`.

Rather than forming this query manually you should consider using [`$wpdb->delete()` helper](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#DELETE_Rows).

Comment: You are correct. I have replaced my query with one using the DELETE helper and it worked fine. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Aaron please note it's considered more in line with site's mechanics to post solution as an answer rather than edit it into question.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE - (SOLVED)
My query now looks like -

```
    // Using where formatting.
    $success = $this->wpdb->delete( $this->table_name,
                    array( 'account_number' => $this->company[$i], 'user' => $this->employee ),
                    array( '%d','%s' ) );
```

This works perfectly.